# Find all holomorphic functions that satisfy $f(x+iy)=f(x)+f(iy)+2xyi$

Tags: complex-analysis

The exercise asks to find  all holomorphic functions that satisfy

$f(x+iy)=f(x)+f(iy)+2xyi$

The only condition I could get is the obvious one: $f$ must verify $f(0)=0$.

I can write $f(x)=g(x)+ih(x)$ and $f(iy)=j(y)+ik(y)$

I am sure there is more to characterize the set of functions that satisfy this equation but I couldn't find more conditions, I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for $z=x+iy$ we have
$$
f'(z)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(z)=f'(x)+2yi
$$
In particular, $f'(iy)=f'(0)+2iy$ for every $y$, and by analytic continuation
we conclude that $f'(z)=f'(0)+2z$ so $f(z)=z^2+\lambda z$ for some constant $\lambda$.
(since $f(0)=0$), and conversely any such function is a solution to the proposed question.